# Threads; Creating a separate thread to periodically do something

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

As an addition to my current application, I need to create a separate thread which will periodically do some processing

I've create a new class to do all this, and this class will be loaded on startup of my application.

This is what I have so far :

```
public class PeriodicChecker extends Thread
{
    static
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new PeriodicChecker());
        while(true)
        {
            t.run();
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(5000l);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Private constructor to prevent instantiation
     */
    private PeriodicChecker()
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("Thread is doing something");
        // Actual business logic here, that is repeated
    }

}
```

I want to make constructor private to prevent other people from attempting to instantiate this class accidentally. How can I achieve this?

Also, is there anything bad about my implementation of such requirements? I'm only creating one thread which will run then sleep, have I missed anything obvious? I haven't worked with threads before

Comment: Starting a thread in a static block? :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have some conceptual erros in your code... for example:

- You should call start() and not run(), because you are running the method sequentially and not simultaneously.
- You can call start() only once, not once in each loop iteration. After that, the thread is in state TERMINATED, you should create a new thread to run it again
- You should not create the thread in the static block, it is a bad practice, and maybe the Thread is running before you want it to run.

You should read some examples about thread, it is a little difficult to unserstand at the beginning, and you can have undesired effects very easily.

Here is a little example, that may do something similar to that you want:

```
public class PeriodicChecker extends Thread
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while(true) {
           System.out.println("Thread is doing something");
           Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
    }

}

public OtherClass {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      Thread t = new PeriodicChecker();
      t.start();
   }
}
```

If you want that none can create a new Thread, you could create a singleton, so you will be sure that none is creating more threads.

Comment: There's one "}" missing after the while loop :)

Answer (score 14):

Java offers [ScheduledExecutorService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) to schedule and run periodic tasks or tasks with delay. It should provide all the features you need. Timer is another class that offers similar functionalities, but I would recommend the ScheduledExecutorService over Timer for its flexibility of configuration and better error management.

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend you to consider [Timer class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) - it provides functionality for periodic tasks execution.
Also you may take a look at ["Timer & TimerTask versus Thread + sleep in Java"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453295/timer-timertask-versus-thread-sleep-in-java) question discussion - there you can find some arguments and examples.

Answer (score 3):

First of all to answer your specific question, you have already achieved your objective. You have declared your constructor to be private meaning no external class can call it like `new PeriodicChecker()`.

Looking at your code however, there are a number of other problems:

Firstly, you are creating an instance of your class within its own static constructor. The purpose of a static constructor is to initialise any static state that your class may have, which instances of your class may then depend on. By creating an instance of the class *within* the static constructor, all of these guarantees go out the window.

Secondly, I don't think your thread is going to behave in the way you expect it to behave, primarily because you don't actually start another thread :). If you intend to start a new thread, you need to call the `start()` method on that thread object. Calling `run()` as you do does not actually create a new thread, but simply runs the `run()` method in the current thread.

Nowadays when you want to create a new thread to do something, the reccomended way of achieving this is to not extend `Thread`, but instead implement the `Runnable` interface. This allows you to decouple the mechanism of the thread, from the behaviour you intend to run.

Based on your requirements, I would suggest doing away with a top-level class like this, and instead create either a private inner class within your application start-up code, or even go for an anonymous inner class:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true) {
                    System.out.println("Thread is doing something");
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is *almost never* right to extend `Thread`. If you ever find yourself doing this, step back, take a look and ask yourself if you really need to change the way the `Thread` class works.

*Almost all* occurances where I see `extends Thread` the job would be better done implementing the `Runnable` interface or using some form of `Timer`.