# Thread.sleep() VS Executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay()

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-sleep, scheduledexecutorservice

Goal: Execute certain code every once in a while.

Question: In terms of performance, is there a significant difference between:

```
while(true) {
    execute();
    Thread.sleep(10 * 1000);
}
```

and

```
executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(runnableWithoutSleep, 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

?

Of course, the latter option is more kosher. Yet, I would like to know whether I should embark on an adventure called "Spend a few days refactoring legacy code to say goodbye to Thread.sleep()".

Update:
This code runs in super/mega/hyper high-load environment.

Comment: I think both are same and `scheduleWithFixedDelay` encapsulated sleep call.

Comment: @Quoi: they aren't really the same, as the scheduled executor can take many scheduled tasks and run them in fewer threads than the number of tasks.  If you just use sleep, you must have a thread for every task you "schedule".

Comment: Why are you asking about performance of a *sleep* operation?

Comment: @Dan: Well, what I see in the thread dump is this: java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping) VS java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking). There's clearly a difference, possibly a performance one too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're dealing with sleep times termed in tens of seconds.  The possible savings by changing your sleep option here is likely nanoseconds or microseconds.

I'd prefer the latter style every time, but if you have the former and it's going to cost you a lot to change it, "improving performance" isn't a particularly good justification.

*EDIT* re: 8000 threads

8000 threads is an awful lot; I might move to the scheduled executor just so that you can control the amount of load put on your system.  Your point about varying wakeup times is something to be aware of, although I would argue that the bigger risk is a stampede of threads all sleeping and then waking in close succession and competing for all the system resources.

I would spend the time to throw these all in a fixed thread pool scheduled executor.  Only have as many running concurrently as you have available of the most limited resource (for example, # cores, or # IO paths) plus a few to pick up any slop.  This will give you good throughput at the expense of latency.

With the `Thread.sleep()` method it will be very hard to control what is going on, and you will likely lose out on both throughput *and* latency.

If you need more detailed advice, you'll probably have to describe what you're trying to do in more detail.

Comment: My concern is that we have 8,000 threads and the sleeping threads may get such a low priority that they will execute with a significant delay, possibly spawning collateral problems with GC.

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't mentioned the Java version, so, things might change.

As I recall from the source code of Java, the prime difference that comes is the way things are written internally.

For **Sun Java 1.6** if you use the second approach the native code also brings in the **wait and notify** calls to the system. So, in a way more thread efficient and CPU friendly.

But then again you loose the control and it becomes more unpredictable for your code - consider you want to sleep for 10 seconds.

So, if you want more predictability - surely you can go with option 1.

Also, on a side note, in the legacy systems when you encounter things like this - 80% chances there are now better ways of doing it- but the magic numbers are there for a reason(the rest 20%) so, change it at own risk :)

Answer (score 1):

There are different scenarios,

1. The Timer creates a queue of tasks that is continually updated. When the Timer is done, it may not be garbage collected immediately. So creating more Timers only adds more objects onto the heap. Thread.sleep() only pauses the thread, so memory overhead would be extremely low
2. Timer/TimerTask also takes into account the execution time of your task, so it will be a bit more accurate. And it deals better with multithreading issues (such as avoiding deadlocks etc.).
3. If you thread get exception and gets killed, that is a problem. But TimerTask will take care of it. It will run irrespective of failure in previous run
4. The advantage of TimerTask is that it expresses your intention much better (i.e. code readability), and it already has the cancel() feature implemented.

Reference is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453295/timer-timertask-versus-thread-sleep-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You said you are running in a "mega... high-load environment" so if I understand you correctly you have many such threads simultaneously sleeping like your code example. It takes less CPU time to reuse a thread than to kill and create a new one, and the refactoring may allow you to reuse threads.

You can create a thread pool by using a [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) with a `corePoolSize` greater than 1. Then when you call [scheduleWithFixedDelay](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay) on that thread pool, if a thread is available it will be reused.

This change may reduce CPU utilization as threads are being reused rather than destroyed and created, but the degree of reduction will depend on the tasks they're doing, the number of threads in the pool, etc. Memory usage will also go down if some of the tasks overlap since there will be less threads sitting idle at once.