# Create a thread which never ends

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to create a thread which never halts. Every second it will acquire the system time and display this on the console. This is what I have so far:

```
public class Test implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
}
```

I'd like to avoid using a loop.

Comment: Do `while (true)`

Comment: That is evil...Grrr...Why so many downvotes here ??? Where is SO going ??? Seems a valid question to me. OP might learning it.

Comment: Whatever you do, **don't** use a `for(;;)` and a `sleep` or any similar vulgarity. Use the facilities already available to you in java: one of the executor service classes will suffice here.

Comment: bt i dont want use any kind of loops

Comment: -8? Come on guys. Question is well-posed (even before my edit), with "what I've tried so far" code. What is the objection to this? Questions are the life blood of this site.

Answer (score 2):

Using `while(true)` and `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep` is a possibility, but it is bad practice (as you can see from the sheer number of downvotes on this post). [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453295/timer-timertask-versus-thread-sleep-in-java) gives some reasons as to why:

- low level, subject to spurious wakeups
- clock drift
- control
- intent of code

there are others.

The basic way to achieve this is to use a [`java.util.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html), not to be confused with a `javax.swing.Timer`:

```
final Timer timer = new Timer("MyTimer");
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
}, 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1));
```

You need to call `timer.cancel()` to stop the timer - as the timer is running a non-daemon thread your program will not exit until that is done.

A more advanced way, which allows multiple tasks to be scheduled to run at different intervals on a pool of the [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). This allows you to `scheduleAtFixedRate` which runs a task every second (regardless of how long it takes to run, i.e. the gap between *start* times is always the same) or `scheduleWithFixedDelay` which runs a task at one second intervals (i.e. the gap between the end of one run and the start of the next is always the same).

For example:

```
final ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
final ScheduledFuture<?> handle = executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
}, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

To cancel the particular task you would call `handle.cancel(false)` (as interrupting has no effect) and to stop the `executorService` you would call `executorService.shutdown()` after which you might want to add a `executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)` to wait for all the tasks to finish.

**EDIT**

A comment *This can be done more concisely in java 8 with lambda right? (not an expert at lambdas)*

The first example, no. A `Timer` takes a `TimerTask`, this is an `abstract class` and not an `@FunctionalInterface` so a lambda is not possible. In the second case, sure:

```
final ScheduledFuture<?> handle = executorService.
        scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()), 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: This can be done more concisely in java 8 with lambda right? (not an expert at lambdas)

Comment: @AshishSrivastava what did I say? Make sure you are **not** using a `javax.swing.Timer`!

Comment: @Cruncher added something on that.

Comment: @AshishSrivastava what is the _exact_ compiler error you are getting?

Comment: import java.util.Timer;

public class Test implements Runnable {

 
final Timer timer = new Timer("MyTimer");
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
}, 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1));
   
}
illegal start expression

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57810/discussion-between-ashish-srivastava-and-boris-the-spider).

Comment: It's looks suspiciously like you area sticking arbitrary code into a class rather than a block or method. Is that the case? As the compiler points out that is invalid.

Comment: actually i have an IP camera which is have an IP address i want to check the camera is alive or not so i already create TCP listener but i want listener is run with some time interval that's mean i have to use a thread bt there is condition from my senior they don't want use any kind of loop to do this so tell what i have to do for achieve this functionality and also listener is always run its mean thread which is never end

Comment: Right, I'm not sure how that's relevant. The code you posted is invalid, correct the compiler error and it will work.

Comment: A syntax error _is a_ compiler error. I will repeat what I said, correct your syntax.

Comment: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Duplicate field name&signature in class file demo/Test

Comment: public class Test implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        
        Test ts = new Test();
        ts.run();
    }
 
final Timer timer = new Timer("MyTimer");
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
}, 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1));
   
}