# Wait without try-catch

Tags: java, delay, wait

I am working on a Java program that runs forever, but I don't know how to delay each loop for one second without using 'try catch'. I've tried

```java
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TimeUnit wait = new TimeUnit();
        while (true) {
            wait.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        }
    }
}
```

but it didn't seem to work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: There is no need to create an instance of TimeUnit. SECONDS is a static field, so you can refer to it directly as TimeUnit.SECONDS. Also, if you don't want to use try-catch, you can do `public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException`,

Comment: Hello! Why are you trying to delay every loop by a second? Do you have tasks that need to run once every second? Or are you waiting for something to finish? What is your goal?

Comment: Why don't you want a try/catch?

Comment: @k314159 thank you this helped me the most

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone said that I should do this

```java
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class program {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        while (true) {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        }
    }
}
```

and it worked. Thank you that person

Answer (score 5):

After contemplating this for a while I do agree that Thread.sleep is the straight forward way to stall the main thread in a loop obviously.

In other use cases that may be differnt, though, since, well, it stalls a thread that could do something else in the meantime. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453295/timer-timertask-versus-thread-sleep-in-java) you have a discussion of Timer vs Thread.sleep, if you're interested and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104313/how-do-i-make-a-delay-in-java) another somewhat less comprehensive answers for a question that could pass as a duplicate.

```
public static void sleep(int someDelay) {
   try {
      Thread.sleep(someDelay);
   } 
   catch (InterruptedException e) {
      Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
   }
}
```

For more demanding scenarios [`ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) is your friend.

```
    ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(poolSize);
    executor.schedule(() -> {
        // doSmthg
    }, 12, TimeUnit.HOURS);
```

Another way to go was Timer/Timertask, which is now usually [discouraged](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) (thx to @rkosegi for pointing this out) in favor of ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor. A poolsize of 1 mimicks Timer/Timertask functionality.

On the other hand Timer/Timertask has the upper hand for large numbers of small tasks in a single thread scenario "Implementation note: *This class scales to large numbers of concurrently scheduled tasks (thousands should present no problem). Internally, it uses a binary heap to represent its task queue, so the cost to schedule a task is O(log n), where n is the number of concurrently scheduled tasks.*", where ScheduledExecutorService uses a BlockingQueue.

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // do smthg;
        }
    }, someDelay);
```

Comment: In fact this answer could be very useful to the OP, as I suspect it's an [X-Y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). A timer task could be better suited than a wait in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way is to create a method.

```
public static void sleep(int delay) {
   try {
       TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(delay);
   } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
      Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
   }
}
```

Now just call the method when ever you need to sleep.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    System.out.println(i);
    sleep(1);  // 1 second
}
```

Comment: Ignoring IntereuptedException is never a Good idea. At least set the interruption flag again

Comment: It's common, almost to the point of being idiomatic, to do it for Sleep.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Thread.sleep(TIME_FOR_DELAY)` line for delay But you have to put it inside `try-catch` block

```
try{
   //TODO before wait

   Thread.sleep(TIME_FOR_DELAY);

   //TODO after wait
}catch(InterruptedException e){
   // 
}
```